# Detach Ubuntu Pro Personal from Broken Device

Tags: 22.04, support

I have a Ubuntu Pro Personal Subscription. However the device attached to the subscription had to be reset. The issue I am having is the Ubuntu Pro dashboard still reports ( https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard ) that the 1 device is still attached to the subscription. I can't remove it via `sudo pro detach` cause it had to be reset and the device itself isn't attached to my Ubuntu Pro Personal Subscription. If I attach the reset device via `sudo apt attach <token>` I will have 2 devices the `phantom` device and the resetted device which is one and the same. How do i remove that resetted device manually from my Ubuntu Pro Personal subscription?